# How to generate random token on app/Mail VeryfyMail.php on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.7 and I have VeryfyMail system. I need sending some random number to subject on email in app/Mail VeryfyMail.php file,

VeryfyMail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class VerifyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        //return $this->view('emails.verifyUser');
        return $this->subject('')->view('emails.verifyUser');
    }
}
```

how can I generate some ramdon number on above file subject?

Comment: To generate a random hex-string, you can use [random_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php), which you then convert to hex. Example: `$random = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));`. The number `16` is the number of random bytes you want.

Comment: can you send me how can I use this on My file?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Random numbers can be generated using `rand()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you want he random token as the subject, just do:

#### Getting a random string (hex)

When creating tokens, you usually want something that's cryptographically secure to make it much harder for clever attackers to "guess" the tokens. Luckily, PHP introduced [random_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) in PHP 7.

This will create a hexadecimal random token:

```
// Get some random bytes
$token = random_bytes(8);

// Since random_bytes() returns a string with all kinds of bytes, 
// it can't be presented "as is".
// We need to convert it to a better format. Let's use hex
$token = bin2hex($token)

// Now just add the variable as the subject
return $this->subject($token)->view('emails.verifyUser');
```

#### Getting a random number (integer)

If you rather want only numbers, we can use [random_int()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) instead:

```
// Generate the token. Add the min and max value
$token = random_int(1000000, 9999999);

// Use it as the subject
return $this->subject($token)->view('emails.verifyUser');
```

Comment: may I use this in build function?

Comment: @banda - You may use it where ever you want and need.

Comment: Can this be done with rand() function? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @Pie - You can, but if you care about security, you shouldn't. From the manual about `rand()` - _"Caution
This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead."_ - It's better to just wrap the above code in a custom function you can use in your code instead.

Comment: Does token generation requires encryption? why?@MagnusEriksson

Comment: @Pie - Generating tokens has nothing to do with encryption. But you do want to use the best function for creating random bytes (or pseudo random bytes, to be accurate), which, in PHP, currently is `random_bytes()`. Other random functions, like `rand()` might be enough in many cases, but for tokens, you want the best random bytes that is much harder to "guess".

Comment: he wanted to create random tokens. My question is why do token generation requires "cryptographically secure values" ? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @Pie - Because tokens are usually used as an identifier of sorts. It could be for email verification, access to an API or what ever. Then you definitely want the token to be generated properly so attackers can't "reproduce" the tokens, since they then potentially can gain access to someone's account or similar.